# Where can I find an Mavericks driver for my Alfa AWUS036H

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have a MacBook Pro Intel Core i7 and have just installed OS X Mavericks (10.9.2) and now can not use my [Alfa AWUS036H](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WCEWU8) USB antenna. It seams there are no new drives for this model. Is there a workaround for this or can another model be recommend the runs on OS X Mavericks?

Comment: Hey david, can I ask you to flesh out your question a little, provide info on what is happening and even what your Alfa device is (perhaps a link)?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Alfa web site](http://www.alfa.com.tw) (no direct link to FAQ entry available):

> Q: Does AWUS036H has driver for Mac Lion?
>
> The AWUS036H works on 32-bit Mac only. If your Mac system is running on 32-bit CPU and you just upgrade the Mac OS to latest version then your AWUS036H is still compatible to it. However, if you just purchased Mac system with 10.6.8 or later version who is running on 64-bit Mac system then you have to boot your computer into 32-bit in order to run the application with device. And you can find the installation guide through our blog @ http://alfanetworkinc.blogspot.com/2011/08/install-awus036h-onto-mac-os-107.html
>
> To identify whether your Mac system is running in 64-bit or not, http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3770
>
> If you like to use wifi adapter with default 64-bit Mac system then we’ll suggest following models -  AWUS036NH, AWUS036NEH, AWUS051NH, AWUS036NHR and AWUS036NHV.

Answer (score 0):

You can reboot the system into 32 bit mode by pressing 3 and 2 during reboot, or by passing

```
systemsetup -setkernelbootarchitecture i386
```

to the command line as root. The former option works until the next reboot. The latter one is persistent.

Answer (score -3):

Mavericks only runs in 64bit mode. You can run KISMAC in 32bit by setting the "Get Info" checkbox. However, the USB driver for the Alpha is only for 32bit mode. Looks like the Alpha USB driver will have to be re-written to support 64bit. If someone has a solution please chime in...